# How to create specialized function for tuple elements by their type

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I want to write a function that performs an operation on each element of a `std::tuple` but is specialized so that if the element is of a certain type, it will do one thing, and if it is of another type, it will do another thing. I have code that can do the same thing on every element:

```
template<std::size_t I = 0, class ...Ts>
inline typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof...(Ts), void>::type
tupel_el_func(std::tuple<Ts...> &t) { } // base case: do nothing

template<std::size_t I = 0, class... Ts>
inline constexpr typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(Ts), void>::type
tupel_el_func(std::tuple<Ts...> &t) {

    auto el = std::get<I>(t);
    // do thing with el
    tupel_el_func<I+1, Ts...>(t);
}
```

but now I need to specialize this function to do a different thing for elements that are of a certain type (e.g. type `char*`). I have tried using `std::enable_if` like so but it will not compile:

```
template<int N, typename... Ts>
using NthTypeOf = typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type;

template<std::size_t I = 0, class... Ts>
inline constexpr typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(Ts) && std::is_same<char*, NthTypeOf<I, Ts...>>::value, void>::type
tupel_el_func(std::tuple<Ts...> &t) {
    // function body for when get<I>(t) is a char*
}

template<std::size_t I = 0, class... Ts>
inline constexpr typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(Ts) && !std::is_same<char*, NthTypeOf<I, Ts...>>::value, void>::type
tupel_el_func(std::tuple<Ts...> &t) {
    // function body for generic next element
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Not C++14?  That's bad.

Comment: Yeah need to be in C++11 not 14

Comment: Why C++11?  What compiler does it need to support?  Many had some C++14 features, which make this much easier.

Comment: Interesting. I was told to implement this "using C+11 features". It wasn't explicitly said that C++14 features could not be used. I think I have actually figured out a way to do it though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the logic of the element processing function with specialized/generic functions that implement the logic for the particular cases for each type:

```
template<std::size_t I = 0, class ...Ts>
inline typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof...(Ts), void>::type
tupel_el_func(std::tuple<Ts...> &t) { } // base case: do nothing

template<std::size_t I = 0, class... Ts>
inline constexpr typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(Ts), void>::type
tupel_el_func(std::tuple<Ts...> &t) {
    do_logic(get<I>(t));
    tupel_el_func<I+1>(t);
}
```

and then have specialized/generic `do_logic` functions like so:

```
template <class T>
void do_logic(T element) {
   // generic logic
}

template <>
void do_logic(char* element) {
   // char* logic
}
```

Comment: This worked for me (completely solved my problem) so idk why the downvote

Comment: You have recursion with no base case.

Comment: Isn't the base case in the question statement?

Comment: Better to incldue it here also, but ok, fair enough, I'll remove the downvote. That said, recursion still isnt' the best way to go about it, see other answer. Edit: I can't remove downvote unless you edit something. So, just copy and paste the base case and I'll remove it :-).

Comment: Ahh Got it. I will attempt to use your very thorough answer without recursion. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I propose to completely avoid the recursion.

The bad point is that you use C++11, so you can't use C++14 features like `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence`.

But you can easily simulate they; by example with

```
template <std::size_t ...>
struct indexSequence
 { };

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Next>
struct indexSequenceHelper 
 { using type = typename indexSequenceHelper<N-1U, N-1U, Next ... >::type; };

template <std::size_t ... Next>
struct indexSequenceHelper<0U, Next ... >
 { using type = indexSequence<Next ... >; };

template <std::size_t N>
using makeIndexSequence = typename indexSequenceHelper<N>::type;
```

Now, you can write a function `foo()` that receive a generic `std::tuple` object and call an helper function `fooH()` passing the tuple and, in a `range`, a list of indexes (from zero to `N-1` for a `std::tuple` with `N` types`)

```
template <typename ... Ts>
void foo (std::tuple<Ts...> const & t)
 { fooH(t, makeIndexSequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{}); }
```

Next, without recursion and using `std::get` and indexes, you can implement the helper function to execute, over every element in the tuple, a function `bar()`

```
template <typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Is>
void fooH (std::tuple<Ts...> const & t, indexSequence<Is...> const &)
 { 
   using unused = int[];

   (void)unused { 0, ((void)bar(std::get<Is>(t)), 0)... };
 }
```

Now you develop a generic template `bar()` function

```
template <typename T>
void bar (T const & t)
 { std::cout << "- generic bar(): " << t << std::endl; }
```

and as many specific overloaded version, for specific types (for `long`, in the following example), as you want

```
void bar (long l)
 { std::cout << "- bar(), long version: " << l << std::endl; }
```

The following is a full C++11 working example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t ...>
struct indexSequence
 { };

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Next>
struct indexSequenceHelper 
 { using type = typename indexSequenceHelper<N-1U, N-1U, Next ... >::type; };

template <std::size_t ... Next>
struct indexSequenceHelper<0U, Next ... >
 { using type = indexSequence<Next ... >; };

template <std::size_t N>
using makeIndexSequence = typename indexSequenceHelper<N>::type;

template <typename T>
void bar (T const & t)
 { std::cout << "- generic bar(): " << t << std::endl; }

void bar (long l)
 { std::cout << "- bar(), long version: " << l << std::endl; }

template <typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Is>
void fooH (std::tuple<Ts...> const & t, indexSequence<Is...> const &)
 { 
   using unused = int[];

   (void)unused { 0, ((void)bar(std::get<Is>(t)), 0)... };
 }

template <typename ... Ts>
void foo (std::tuple<Ts...> const & t)
 { fooH(t, makeIndexSequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{}); }

int main ()
 {
   std::tuple<short, int, long, long long> t { 0, 1, 2L, 3LL };

   foo(t);
 }
```

Comment: It would be better to just implement index_sequence and make_index_sequence exactly, so OP a) learns how to use them, and b) when they switch to 14 they can just delete their implementation.

Comment: @NirFriedman - well... I don't think that it's a good idea to use *exactly* the same names but... good point; as usual my choice of names is horrible. Answer modified with better (I hope) names.